# first attempt at python, error ("IndexError: index 8 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 8") and efficiency question

Tags: python, loops

learning python, just began last week, havent otherwise coded for about 20 years and was never that advanced to begin with. I got the hello world thing down. Now im trying to back test FX pairs. Any help up the learning curve appreciated, and of course scouring this site while on my Lynda vids.

Getting a funky error, and also wondering if theres blatantly more efficient ways to loop through columns of excel data the way I am.

The spreadsheet being read is simple ... 56 FX pairs down column A, and 8 rows over where the column headers are dates, and the cells in each column are the respective FX pair closing price on that date. The strategy starts at the top of the 2nd column (so that there is a return % that can be calc'd vs the prior priord) and calcs out period/period % returns for each pair, identifying which is the 'maximum value', and then "goes long" that highest performer ... whose performance in the subsequent period/period is recorded as PnL to the portfolio ("p" in the code), loops through that until the current, most recent column is read.

The error relates to using 8 columns instead of 7 ... works when i limit the loop to 7 columns but not 8. When I used 8 I get a wall of text concluding with "IndexError: index 8 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 8" Similar error when i use too many rows, 56 instead of 55, think im missing the bottom row.

Here's my code:
,,,

```
enter code here
#set up imports
import pandas as pd 

#import spreadsheet 
x1 = pd.ExcelFile(r"C:\Users\Gamblor\Desktop\Python\test2020.xlsx")
df = pd.read_excel(x1, "Sheet1", header=1)

#define counters for loops
o = 1 # observation counter
c = 3 # column counter
r = 0 # active row counter for sorting through for max

#define identifiers for the portfolio
rpos = 0 # static row, for identifying which currency pair is in column 0 of that row
p = 100 # portfolio size starts at $100

#define the stuff we are evaluating for
pair = df.iat[r,0] # starting pair at 0,0 where each loop will begin
pair_pct_rtn = 0 # starts out at zero, becomes something at first evaluation, then gets 
compared to each subsequent eval
pair_pct_rtn_calc = 0 # a second version of above, for comparison to prior return

#runs a loop starting at the top to find the max period/period % return in a specific column

while (c < 8): # manually limiting this to 5 columns left to right

    while (r < 55): # i am manually limiting this to 55 data rows per the spreadsheet ... would be better if automatic

        pair_pct_rtn_calc = ((df.iat[r,c])/(df.iat[r,c-1]) - 1)

        if pair_pct_rtn_calc > pair_pct_rtn: # if its a higher return, it must be the "max" to that point
            pair = df.iat[r,0] # identifies the max pair for this column observation, so far
            pair_pct_rtn = pair_pct_rtn_calc # sets pair_pct_rtn as the new max
            rpos = r # identifies the max pair's ROW for this column observation, so far

        r = r + 1 # adds to r in order to jump down and calc the next row

    print('in obs #', o ,', ', pair ,'did best at' ,pair_pct_rtn ,'.')
    o = o + 1

    # now adjust the portfolio by however well USDMXN did in the subsequent week

    p = p * ( 1 + ((df.iat[rpos,c+1])/(df.iat[rpos,c]) - 1))
    print('then the subsequent period it did: ',(df.iat[rpos,c+1])/(df.iat[rpos,c]) - 1)
    print('resulting in portfolio value of', p)
    rpos = 0
    r = 0
    pair_pct_rtn = 0
    c = c + 1 # adds to c in order to move to the next period to the right

print(p)
```

Comment: Python is a zero indexing language. So anything of size 8, is indexed 0 to 7, and  thus 8 is out of bounds.

Answer (score 0):

Since indices are labelled from 0 onwards, the 8th element you are looking for will have index 7. Likewise, row index 55 (the 56th row) will be your last row.